# Azure API Management with OAuth2.0 and AAD?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

im currently developing a mobile app that will make some web services call via the Azure API management. Now, this mobile app is going to be used by public users.

My question is: Do I need to register all public users into AAD to be able to use OAuth2.0 when the mobile apps makes a call to the Azure API management?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your need. If you need to capture end user identities and want to use AAD as the Identity Provider, then you need to register your users in AAD (or ask them to do it).

Otherwise, you can just create client credentials for your mobile app. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx

Comment: thanks, I do not wish to capture their identity and do not want them to register. But i need the OAuth to authorize web services when they use the mobile app to make web services call to Azure APIM. Any suggestion?